# Work tracking in Entity Framework 6 code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I want to implement a program and log all events (insert, update, delete)
and save them in my database.

I use EF codefirst, ASP.NET MVC.

This is my code:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    int SaveAllChanges();    
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}
```

My context is :

```
public class cmsContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public int SaveAllChanges()
    {
        #region Tracker
        var changeInfo = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                             .Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Modified)
                             .Select(t => new
                                         {
                                             Original = t.OriginalValues.PropertyNames.ToDictionary(pn => pn, pn => t.OriginalValues[pn]),
                                             Current = t.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.ToDictionary(pn => pn, pn => t.CurrentValues[pn]),
                                         }).ToList();
        #endregion

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

but `changeInfo` is always `0`. What is the problem?

My service code and unitofwork is like this:

```
public AddArticleCategoryStatus Add(ArticleCategory articleCategory)
{
    _articleCategories.Add(articleCategory);     // IdbSet        
    return AddArticleCategoryStatus.AddArticleCategorySuccessfull;
}
```

and in controller my code is :

```
_articleCategoryService.Add(Category);
_uow.SaveAllChanges();
```

I want to log all changes and insert them all by value.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
_articleCategories.Add(articleCategory);
```

You are adding the entity, not modifying it. Therefore, the `EntityState` will be `Added`, not `Modified`. And thus, it will not make it through your `Where` filter:

```
.Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Modified)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.Where(t => t.State == EntityState.Added || t.State == EntityState.Deleted || t.State == EntityState.Modified)
```

Keep in mind you may need to rework your `.Select` as `Added` and `Deleted` entities won't have original and current values, respectively.